# Creating View from Another View

Tags: sql, oracle

I haven't found anything online or in any other resource after searching, and I was wondering if you could form a View by joining another view and some other tables?  Something similar to this I guess with Server_ref.part_notification_view being the view getting joined.

```
Create View "PART_NOTIFICATION_VIEW" ("NOTIFICATION_IX", "PART_NBR", "MFG_CD", "PART_CLASS_CD", "LEADTIME", "BILLTO_CUST_NBR", "BILL_TO_ACCT_NM", "CUST_PART_NBR", "LAST_CUST_PO", "LAST_REQ_DT", "QTY_OPEN", "YEAR_USAGE", "AVAILABLE_SALE_STANDARD_QT", "ISSUE_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_DATE", "BRIEF_DESCRIPTION", "NOTIFICATION_TYPE", "ACTUAL_DOCUMENT_LINK", "AFFECTED_PARTS_LIST_DOC_LINK", "EMAIL_LINK", "FILE_FOLDER", "RECOMMENDED_REPLACEMENT", "PCN_TYPE", "IMPACT", "MANUFACTURER_NM", "LAST_BUY_DT", "LAST_SHIP_DT", "SALES_MIN_BUY_QTY", "SALES_MIN_PKG_QTY", "PART_DESC", "BOND_QOH", "BOND_QIT", "BRANCH_QOH", "BRANCH_QIT", "BOND_QTY", "BOND_PIPELINE", "BOND_OP", "BRAND_CD", "STATUS", "COMMENTS")
AS
  SELECT
    svr.notification_ix,
    svr.part_nbr,
    svr.mfg_cd,
    svr.part_class_cd,
    svr.leadtime,
    svr.billto_cust_nbr,
    svr.bill_to_acct_nm,
    svr.cust_part_nbr,
    svr.last_cust_po,
    svr.last_req_dt,
    svr.qty_open,
    svr.year_usage,
    svr.available_sale_standard_qt,
    svr.issue_date,
    svr.effective_date,
    svr.brief_description,
    svr.notification_type,
    svr.actual_document_link,
    svr.affected_parts_list_doc_link,
    svr.email_link,
    svr.file_folder,
    svr.recommended_replacement,
    svr.pcn_type,
    svr.impact,
    svr.manufacturer_nm,
    svr.last_buy_dt,
    svr.last_ship_dt,
    svr.sales_min_buy_qty,
    svr.sales_min_pkg_qty,
    svr.part_desc,
    NVL(svr.bond_qoh, 0)                                                                    AS bond_qoh,
    NVL(svr.bond_qit, 0)                                                                    AS bond_qit,
    NVL(svr.branch_qoh, 0)                                                                  AS branch_qoh,
    NVL(svr.branch_qit, 0)                                                                  AS branch_qit,
    NVL(svr.bond_qoh, 0)      + NVL(svr.bond_qit, 0) + NVL(svr.branch_qoh, 0) + NVL(svr.branch_qit, 0) AS bond_qty,
    NVL(svr.bond_pipeline, 0) + NVL(svr.po_qt, 0)                                                 AS bond_pipeline,
    svr.bond_op,
    svr.brand_cd,
    cs.status,
    cc.comments
  FROM part_notification_view svr
  JOIN css_status cs
  ON svr.part_nbr = cs.part_nbr
  AND svr.mfg_cd = cs.mfg_cd
  AND svr.billto_cust_nbr = cs.account
  JOIN css_comment cc
  ON svr.part_nbr = cc.part_nbr
  AND svr.mfg_cd = cc.mfg_cd
  AND svr.billto_cust_nbr = cc.account;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? There's no reason you couldn't do that (though there may be reasons you shouldn't), but if you've tried and got an error then please show it. And yes to the second part - in your new view you will only be able to refer to `svr.part_nbr`, the underlying tables in the old view cannot be referred to directly.

Comment: Ok, this is what I've come up with. (I've edited the original post with the create table)  Tried running it, but I get SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SVR"."PO_QT": invalid identifier.  I checked the table and it is there, so not sure what is going on here.  Would I be correct in assuming that all the ones before that one work fine?

Comment: I think Oracle evaluates the fields backwards - so probably all the ones after it were fine

Comment: Hmm..that was my worry.  The original view I am using has quite a few tables in it and I'm sure a lot of them have the same fields.  Now I would assume this could only access the ones listed in the original view but I could see how this could be erroneous.

Comment: I guess my best bet would be to just copy the original view into this view and then add what I need.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can certainly have a view that's built on top of another view:

```
create table my_table (id number, name varchar2(20), address varchar2(30));

table MY_TABLE created.

create or replace view my_view_1 as
select id, name
from my_table;

view MY_VIEW_1 created.

create or replace view my_view_2 as
select mv1.id, mv1.name, mt.address
from my_view_1 mv1
join my_table mt on mt.id = mv1.id;

view MY_VIEW_2 created.
```

But you can't reference anything in the underlying tables, including any fields that are not part of the view:

```
create or replace view my_view_3 as
select mv1.id, mv1.name, mv1.address
from my_view_1 mv1
join my_table mt on mt.id = mv1.id;

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MV1"."ADDRESS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

The underlying tables having the same columns isn't an issue, and if you include more than on in the view then you'd have to alias them anyway.

You can sometimes get performance issues doing this, and it might be faster and more reliable - though possibly harder to maintain - if you create your new view against the same base tables, and expand it to include the extra data you want.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yeah, I removed the NVL(svr.bond_qit, 0) AS stuff from all the lines and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Remember to be specific with the select portion of the statement. I got an error with something like: ".. select * ..". Works perfectly as above e.g ".. select mv1.id, mv1.name, mv1.address ..".

Comment: Hello @alex-poole, isn't that obvious that `mv1.address` cannot be referenced (as it doesn't exist...) ?

Comment: @St3an - obvious once you know, but that was part of the question; some of the history seems to have gone but look at the second comment under the question, and the first (remaining) comment under the answer. Jackson had been trying to look at columns that were in the underlying tables but not in the view.

Answer (score 8):

Long answer ...

It's one of the fundamental characteristics of a relational database that there should be no logical difference between tables, queries results, and views (which are simply stored queries). In fact the "relational" refers to the rows of data that are accessible through any one of these. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29

There are of course differences imposed to different degrees by different RDBMSs, particularly when it comes to DDL commands (update, delete, insert), and they all impose restrictions on the kinds of object that DDL can be applied to.

Taking Oracle as an example, the system will allow updates and deletes on key-preserved views, and inserts are possible but rarely used in practice (an "instead of" trigger type is available to allow DDL against any view).

So given all that, you can run a select against:

1. A table
2. A set of joined tables
3. A view
4. A query (commonly referred to as an in-line view)
5. A query joined to a view and a table
6. etc

... and that select can therefore be encapsulated in a view definition.

Short answer: Yes