# CREATE VIEW syntax incorrect (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm trying to create a view from these two tables:

[image]

My current SQL code does not show errors, it just shows zero results:

```
CREATE VIEW `current_job` AS SELECT
  a1.OBJ_NAME,
  a1.TYP,
  a1.OBJ_ID,
  a1.DEVICE_ID,
  a2.DESCRIP,
  a3.CATEGORY,
  a4.INFORMATION    
FROM `job21433` a1, `master_setpoints_view` a2, `master_setpoints_view` a3, `master_setpoints_view` a4
WHERE 
  a1.JOBNUM = "21433189-01"
AND
 a2.DESCRIP = a1.OBJ_NAME
AND
 a3.CATEGORY = a1.OBJ_NAME
AND
 a4.INFORMATION = a1.OBJ_NAME
```

I'm simply trying to get the "DESCRIP", "CATEGORY", AND "INFORMATION" from the master_setpoints_view and add that to my new view.

Can anyone help? Where did I mess up?

**EDIT** The SQL code used to create the view `master_setpoints_view`:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `master_setpoints_view` AS select 
 `a1`.`ID` AS `ID`,
 `a1`.`OBJECT_ID` AS `OBJECT_ID`,
 `a1`.`DESCRIP` AS `DESCRIP`,
 `a2`.`DESCRIP` AS `CATEGORY`,
 `a3`.`SECONDARY` AS `INFORMATION` from ((`master_setpoints_list` `a1` join `setpoint_categories` `a2`) join `setpoint_categories` `a3`) where ((`a2`.`SID` = `a1`.`CATEGORY`) and (`a3`.`SID` = `a1`.`CATEGORY`));
```

Comment: Why are you using four joins? What is your expected output?

Comment: is ```master_setpoints_view``` a view, or is it a table?

Comment: `master_setpoints_view` is a view

Comment: I believe you can't make views from other views in MySQL

Comment: my expected output is to have these columns, `OBJ_NAME`, `TYP`, `DEVICE_ID`, `DESCRIP`, `CATEGORY`, `INFORMATION`

Comment: @amenadiel I've seen other SO posts where people create views from views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834113/creating-view-from-another-view

Comment: My bad, you can use views as select statements. But you can't use subqueries on the FROM clause. This is ambiguous. Depending on the definition of the ```master_setpoints_view``` the MySQL query parser might be trying to do an illegal operation. I'm pretty sure there was a time when you just couldn't do it, but that might have been years ago.

Comment: Whats weird is I never received any errors about illegal operations

Comment: can you add the definition of master_setpoints_view to your original question?

Comment: @amenadiel do you mean how it was constructed?

Comment: yes, the output of ```SHOW CREATE VIEW master_setpoints_view```

Comment: I seems I just need to create two columns on `job21433` and make sure to fill in those columns when i input new data into the table